# Software Updater - No Automatic Updates 2

Tags: apt, updates, automatic

I have exactly the same problem as in Software Updater - No Automatic Updates
[Software Updater - No Automatic Updates](https://askubuntu.com/questions/874562/software-updater-no-automatic-updates).

Short history: When was a problem with automatic software updater, (cannot install some package), I read in forum and did workaround: Install Synaptic package manager and did updates manually. Automatic updates I switch off. After some time I notice, what Ubuntu software updates works correctly, so I switch automatic updates on. But no automatic updates starts.

Screenshot from Software & Updates

[image: Inportant security updates, recommended updates, unsupported updates all checked]

Output from APT:

```
lubomir@lipa:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://sk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://sk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease             
Hit:3 http://sk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease           
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease              
Ign:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu xenial InRelease        
Hit:7 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial InRelease        
Hit:9 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease 
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu xenial Release         
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Hit:5 http://screenshots.getdeb.net xenial-getdeb InRelease                    
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Err:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

---

```
lubomir@lipa:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  akonadi-backend-mysql akonadi-server kde-config-mailtransport kdepim-runtime
  kdepimlibs-data kdepimlibs-kio-plugins kinit kio kpackagelauncherqml
  kpackagetool5 kwayland-data kwayland-integration libaio1
  libboost-thread1.58.0 libfam0 libgrantlee-templates5
  libgrantlee-textdocument5 libkf5akonadiagentbase5 libkf5akonadicalendar5
  libkf5akonadicontact5 libkf5akonadicore-bin libkf5akonadicore5
  libkf5akonadimime5 libkf5akonadinotes5 libkf5akonadiprivate5
  libkf5akonadisearchpim5 libkf5akonadiwidgets5 libkf5alarmcalendar5
  libkf5archive5 libkf5attica5 libkf5auth-data libkf5auth5
  libkf5bookmarks-data libkf5bookmarks5 libkf5calendarcore5
  libkf5calendarsupport5 libkf5calendarutils5 libkf5codecs-data libkf5codecs5
  libkf5completion-data libkf5completion5 libkf5config-bin libkf5config-data
  libkf5configcore5 libkf5configgui5 libkf5configwidgets-data
  libkf5configwidgets5 libkf5contacts-data libkf5contacts5
  libkf5coreaddons-data libkf5coreaddons5 libkf5crash5 libkf5dbusaddons-bin
  libkf5dbusaddons-data libkf5dbusaddons5 libkf5declarative-data
  libkf5declarative5 libkf5emoticons-bin libkf5emoticons-data libkf5emoticons5
  libkf5eventviews5 libkf5followupreminder5 libkf5gapi-data
  libkf5gapicalendar5 libkf5gapicontacts5 libkf5gapicore5 libkf5gapidrive5
  libkf5gapitasks5 libkf5globalaccel-bin libkf5globalaccel-data
  libkf5globalaccel5 libkf5globalaccelprivate5 libkf5gpgmepp-pthread5
  libkf5gpgmepp5 libkf5gravatar5 libkf5guiaddons5 libkf5holidays-data
  libkf5holidays5 libkf5i18n-data libkf5i18n5 libkf5iconthemes-bin
  libkf5iconthemes-data libkf5iconthemes5 libkf5identitymanagement5
  libkf5idletime5 libkf5imap5 libkf5incidenceeditorsng5 libkf5itemmodels5
  libkf5itemviews-data libkf5itemviews5 libkf5jobwidgets-data
  libkf5jobwidgets5 libkf5kcmutils-data libkf5kcmutils5
  libkf5kdelibs4support-data libkf5kdelibs4support5 libkf5kdelibs4support5-bin
  libkf5kdepimdbusinterfaces5 libkf5kdgantt2-5 libkf5kiocore5
  libkf5kiofilewidgets5 libkf5kiontlm5 libkf5kiowidgets5 libkf5ldap5
  libkf5libkdepim5 libkf5libkleo5 libkf5mailcommon5 libkf5mailimporter5
  libkf5mailtransport-data libkf5mailtransport5 libkf5mbox5
  libkf5messagecomposer5 libkf5messagecore5 libkf5messageviewer5 libkf5mime5
  libkf5newstuff-data libkf5newstuff5 libkf5notifications-data
  libkf5notifications5 libkf5notifyconfig-data libkf5notifyconfig5
  libkf5package-data libkf5package5 libkf5parts-data libkf5parts-plugins
  libkf5parts5 libkf5pimcommon5 libkf5pimtextedit5 libkf5qgpgme5
  libkf5quickaddons5 libkf5sendlater5 libkf5service-bin libkf5service-data
  libkf5service5 libkf5solid5 libkf5solid5-data libkf5sonnet5-data
  libkf5sonnetcore5 libkf5sonnetui5 libkf5templateparser5
  libkf5textwidgets-data libkf5textwidgets5 libkf5tnef5 libkf5wallet-bin
  libkf5wallet-data libkf5wallet5 libkf5waylandclient5 libkf5webkit5
  libkf5widgetsaddons-data libkf5widgetsaddons5 libkf5windowsystem-data
  libkf5windowsystem5 libkf5xmlgui-bin libkf5xmlgui-data libkf5xmlgui5
  libkolab1 libkolabxml1v5 libkwalletbackend5-5 libllvm3.8 libllvm3.8:i386
  libllvm4.0 libllvm4.0:i386 libmircommon5 libphonon4qt5-4 libpolkit-qt5-1-1
  libqmi-glib1 libqt5script5 libqt5x11extras5 libqt5xmlpatterns5 libvoikko1
  libxerces-c3.1 linux-headers-4.4.0-101 linux-headers-4.4.0-101-generic
  linux-headers-4.4.0-103 linux-headers-4.4.0-103-generic
  linux-headers-4.4.0-104 linux-headers-4.4.0-104-generic
  linux-headers-4.4.0-108 linux-headers-4.4.0-108-generic
  linux-headers-4.4.0-109 linux-headers-4.4.0-109-generic
  linux-headers-4.4.0-81 linux-headers-4.4.0-81-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-83
  linux-headers-4.4.0-83-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-87
  linux-headers-4.4.0-87-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-91
  linux-headers-4.4.0-91-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-92
  linux-headers-4.4.0-92-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-93
  linux-headers-4.4.0-93-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-96
  linux-headers-4.4.0-96-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-97
  linux-headers-4.4.0-97-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-98
  linux-headers-4.4.0-98-generic linux-image-4.4.0-101-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-103-generic linux-image-4.4.0-104-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-108-generic linux-image-4.4.0-109-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-81-generic linux-image-4.4.0-83-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-87-generic linux-image-4.4.0-91-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-92-generic linux-image-4.4.0-93-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-96-generic linux-image-4.4.0-97-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-98-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-101-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-103-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-104-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-108-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-109-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-81-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-83-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-87-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-91-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-92-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-93-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-96-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-97-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-98-generic linux-signed-image-4.4.0-101-generic
  linux-signed-image-4.4.0-103-generic linux-signed-image-4.4.0-104-generic
  linux-signed-image-4.4.0-108-generic linux-signed-image-4.4.0-109-generic
  linux-signed-image-4.4.0-81-generic linux-signed-image-4.4.0-83-generic
  linux-signed-image-4.4.0-87-generic linux-signed-image-4.4.0-91-generic
  linux-signed-image-4.4.0-92-generic linux-signed-image-4.4.0-93-generic
  linux-signed-image-4.4.0-96-generic linux-signed-image-4.4.0-97-generic
  linux-signed-image-4.4.0-98-generic mysql-client-core-5.7
  mysql-server-core-5.7 sonnet-plugins
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

And here is the output after I removed one obsolete package and run `apt autoremove`:

```
lubomir@lipa:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://sk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://sk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease             
Hit:3 http://sk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease           
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial InRelease        
Hit:6 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]     
Hit:4 http://screenshots.getdeb.net xenial-getdeb InRelease                    
Hit:8 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease            
Fetched 102 kB in 1s (66,1 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
```

---

```
lubomir@lipa:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Screenshot of *Updates* tab from `software-properties-gtk`  is needed, and output of `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get upgrade` (add them to the question).

Comment: I do not understand what you mean software-properties-gtk. I give screenshot of Software & Updates.

Comment: `software-properties-gtk` is the name for *Software & Updates* GUI. I do not see any screenshots.

Comment: How I can put here a screenshot?
/home/lubomir/Pictures/Screenshot from 2018-04-01 15-43-48.png

Comment: [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1020566/edit) your question and put your image by drag-and-drop.

Comment: [FreeFileSync PPA](https://launchpad.net/~freefilesync/+archive/ubuntu/ffs) does not provide packages for Xenial. So you should remove this repository with `sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:freefilesync/ffs`. And then do `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, `sudo apt-get autoremove`. After these actions you will get fully-upgraded system.

Comment: I notice one new OS update today, but no automatic update starts. So, this problem persists.

Comment: Screenshot of  *Ubuntu Software* tab (see [this as example](https://askubuntu.com/a/1023967/66509)) from *software-properties-gtk* is needed and updated  output of `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get upgrade` (add them to the question).