# How to install libc6:i386 on 16.04.4 64bit?

Tags: apt, dpkg

I've been trough all the similar questions I can find on here and elsewhere but still can't get a working solution for this.

Things I've tried:

```
apt-get install libc6:i386
```

This tries to remove most of the currently installed 64bit libraries that if run would leave the machine unusable.

I've run the following based on other questions/answers and still no joy:

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

All complete cleanly but don't change the output of trying to install the 32bit libraries.

The next option was to try:

```
apt-get install libc6-i386
```

Which returns:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies,
 libc6-i386 : Depends: libc6 (= 2.23-0ubuntu3) but 2.23-0ubuntu10 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

This error appears misleading as `apt-mark showhold` returns no packages.

The end goal here is to install Symantec's AV package which needs the 32bit libraries.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure you have enabled all sections in *Software & Updates* and selected good mirror (I prefer *Main server*) in

1. *Ubuntu Software*

   [image: su1]
2. and *security-updates* in *Updates*:

   [image: su2]

Then `sudo apt-get install libc6:i386` will be enough.

Or deeper:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386
sudo apt-get install -f
```

On my system libc:i386 is installed with version [2.23-0ubuntu10](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/libc6).

Comment: Thanks, I'd tried flipping mirrors, but missed that who ever had done the initial install hadn't enabled any of the update repos (which is just nuts)

Comment: As of Cosmic this is broken.

Answer (score 1):

1. Boot the Operating System into recovery mode

   [Screenshot of recovery mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WscC9.png)
2. Select 'root -Drop to root shell prompt' in the Recovery menu
3. Then

`dpkg --add-architecture i386 -f` (for force install)

`apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get dist-upgrade`

4. Then reboot normally.

I was having the same problem because I installed some 3rd party packages which corrupted the `dpkg` and broke the dependencies. 
After trying all these answers I was gonna reinstall Ubuntu, it is when I got the idea to try Recovery mode.

Comment: I got same issue with same cause during my new install of Ubuntu 18, really helps. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure your backups are in order

Run the following:

```
apt-get upgrade
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

You can make your machine support both i386 and amd64 by using

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

I solved the problem by downloading **libc6:i386.deb** from [https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libc6](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.04/ubuntu-main-i386/libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1_i386.deb.html)

and executing

```
sudo dpkg -i xxx1.deb
```

Try to install it normally, but if there are some errors about overwriting  /xxx/xxx/doc/xxx/xxx，you can just ignore it by running:

```
sudo dpkg --force-overwrite -i xxx1.deb
```

My Ubuntu version is 18.04, not the same as yours: make sure you select the correct download for your Ubuntu version

Answer (score 0):

add x32 architecture 
`$` sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386

next! - rebuild your libs in repo 
`$` sudo apt --fix-broken install

next -> try to install your package 
`$` sudo dpkg -i xxx1.deb