# Problem Installing Wine in Ubuntu Studio 20.04

Tags: wine, 20.04, configuration, ubuntu-studio

Trying to install Wine on Ubuntu Studio 20.04. Gets to about 50%,and then displays two errors. I've tried a few times. This is what I'm getting:

```
E: Could not configure libc6:i386.
```

Also receiving this:

```
E:Could not perform immediate configuration on 'libgcc-s1:i386'. 
Please see man 5 apt.conf under APT::Immediate-Configure for details. (2)
```

I've searched other questions/answers, but I'm not finding this issue. Again, I'm *brand new* to Ubuntu, and am thankful for any guidance.

Comment: What command did you run to install Wine ? I just want to replicate your situation to get  more info.Please add it to your question

Comment: `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`  gives?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following commands:

```
sudo apt install -f  
sudo apt autoremove  
sudo apt install libc6-dev  
sudo apt update  
sudo apt upgrade  
sudo apt install wine64 wine32
```

Comment: Thanks for the help... I got all the way to install lib6-dev, and I get a return of "unable to locate package lib6-dev"... where might I go from there?

Comment: sorry, I missed something. have a look here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1023962/how-to-install-libc6i386-on-16-04-4-64bit

Answer (score 0):

I had same error message installing Wine in docker container using the following command.

```
$ install -y --install-recommends winehq-stable;
```

Workaround described [here](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/1131#issuecomment-713029736) worked for me.

```
$ install -y -o APT::Immediate-Configure=0 --install-recommends \
        winehq-stable;
```