# Java JDK won't install

Tags: dpkg, java, jdk

I'm trying to install Java JDK per [this YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ajKhjoWQTYI):. I get to the part where I run `sudo dpkg -i <FILENAME>` and it gives me this:

```
(Reading database ... 185728 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack javajava.deb ...
Unpacking jdk-17 (17.0.2-ga) over (17.0.2-ga) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of jdk-17:
 jdk-17 depends on libc6-i386; however:
  Package libc6-i386 is not installed.
 jdk-17 depends on libc6-x32; however:
  Package libc6-x32 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package jdk-17 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 jdk-17
```

I noticed I'm missing a couple of packages, so I tried running `sudo apt-get install libc6:i386`. That throws a similar error about dependencies on yet more packages.

I've also run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You've not mentioned your OS, release and architecture details.  The package version you did provide doesn't match any *supported* release.

Comment: @guiverc Java Oracle 17 is available. https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/ The Oracle website says.

Comment: See this for a potential solution to your situation: https://askubuntu.com/questions/40011/how-to-let-dpkg-i-install-dependencies-for-me

Comment: if you just want jdk do sudo apt install openjdk-17-jdk

Answer (score 7):

While installing java jdk i also got the same type of this problem.to fibure that read terminal error carefully.
It tells,

```
jdk-18 depends on libc6-i386; however:
  Package libc6-i386 is not installed.
```

to figure this,

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

After that unpack debian package again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install them together. I go through the process below.

Reproduced the error:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i jdk-17.0.1_linux-x64_bin.deb 

(Reading database ... 181449 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack jdk-17.0.1_linux-x64_bin.deb ...
Unpacking jdk-17 (17.0.1-ga) over (17.0.1-ga) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of jdk-17:
 jdk-17 depends on libc6-i386; however:
  Package libc6-i386 is not installed.
 jdk-17 depends on libc6-x32; however:
  Package libc6-x32 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package jdk-17 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 jdk-17
```

Solution:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 libc6-x32

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  systemd-hwe-hwdb
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libc6-i386 libc6-x32
0 to upgrade, 2 to newly install, 0 to remove and 99 not to upgrade.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 5,815 kB of archives.
After this operation, 25.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libc6-i386 amd64 2.35-0ubuntu3.1 [2,837 kB]
Get:2 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libc6-x32 amd64 2.35-0ubuntu3.1 [2,978 kB]
Fetched 5,815 kB in 1s (5,290 kB/s)  
Selecting previously unselected package libc6-i386.
(Reading database ... 181449 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libc6-i386_2.35-0ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libc6-i386 (2.35-0ubuntu3.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libc6-x32.
Preparing to unpack .../libc6-x32_2.35-0ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libc6-x32 (2.35-0ubuntu3.1) ...
Setting up libc6-x32 (2.35-0ubuntu3.1) ...
Setting up libc6-i386 (2.35-0ubuntu3.1) ...
Setting up jdk-17 (17.0.1-ga) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.1) ...
```

Confirmation:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i jdk-17.0.1_linux-x64_bin.deb 

(Reading database ... 182019 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack jdk-17.0.1_linux-x64_bin.deb ...
Unpacking jdk-17 (17.0.1-ga) over (17.0.1-ga) ...
Setting up jdk-17 (17.0.1-ga) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

press Alt+F2 and Enter “update-manager -cd” to go to software and security and check all the boxes like the answer to this link
[How to install libc6:i386 on 16.04.4 64bit?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1023962/how-to-install-libc6i386-on-16-04-4-64bit)

then open the terminal, where you have downloaded the .deb file and run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg -i filename.deb
```

This worked for me :)